# To get the location of the building

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Is it possible to get the location of the building shown in the Camera view using Augmented Reality in Android??

I have the GPS coordinates of the mobile but now i want to get the GPS coordinates of the building  shown in the Camera view???

Please suggest me some ideas?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the GPS coordinate of your mobile phone and the direction (using the compass of the mobile phone) in which it is hold, you could use some trigonometry to approximate the location of the building. The remaining problem is that you have to somewhere estimate how far the building is away from your phone.

But if you assume for example that you're always walking in streets and the point to a building, it should be easier to find the building.

Comment: The tricky bit with this is that you need an accurate fix on your position, which tall buildings can interfere with.

Comment: @Phil Lello yes that is true, however it is the only possibility I can think of.

Comment: I haven't got anything better (unless maybe OCR on the building name/number). I guess you could project a line from the known position in the direction of the camera, and intersect with the road edge (from a map). Failing that, I think you'd need a 3D model of the area, and then try to match camera + position to the map, but the data you'd need to capture tons of 3D mapping data first.

Answer (score 0):

I would not depend on the compass output, it's always in question.

What I did was use Gogle maps, get a location fix, draw the point on the map (if you want to draw a line use bearing that would be a better hint I guess) then let the user draw or adjust the line using sattelite view to pinpoint the target. You can then get the new geo-coord and get a fairly accurate bearing ( if that's required )

I would also suggest using both the network and gps provider, in cities sometimes the network provider is more accurate than the GPS if the glass/metal canyon is preventing it, even a couple of hundred yards can get you close to your position.

Anyway it's a somewhat manual process but it's more reliable then trying to guess distance and hoping the azimuth is reliable (rarely is)